# Let $C$ be a straight line segment from $0$ to $1+3i$. Find the contour integral...

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $C$ be a straight line segment from $0$ to $1+3i$. Find $\int_cIm(z)dz$.

I tried:

Let $z(t)=t+i3t$ where $t\in[0,1]$

Then, $\int_cIm(z)dz=\int_0^13t(1+3i)dt=\frac{3+9i}{2}$.

Note: $Im(z) = Im(t+i3t)=3t$ which gets multiplied with $\frac{d(t+i3t)}{dt}=1+3i$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.  Well done!